# Is the unit sphere in $C_1^0 \big([0,1], \mathbb{R}\big)$ totally bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

let $X=\Big( \mathcal{C}_1^0 \big([0,1], \mathbb{R}\big), \|\cdot \|_1 \Big)  $ be the space of real-valued continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ **with the norm** $\|\cdot \|_1$,  $$ \| f \|_1:= \int_0^1 |f(t)|\,dt. $$
Let us also denote the unit sphere in $X$ by $S_X:= \big\{ f\in X: \|f \|_1 =1 \big\}$.

Is $S_X$ totally bounded in $ X$?

I bet it is not, but I can't manage to prove it. First, while $S_X$ is not compact, $X$ is not a Banach space, so one can't use that  a subset $A$ of a metric space $Y$ is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded. (This argument works flawlessly for every infinite-dimensional Banach space, but not here)

I've also tried to get a contradiction by taking several equivalences and implications on being totally bounded, and thereafter supposing that $S_X$ is totally bounded, but none of them works here (or at least none of those of which I'm aware of)

Can you provide me with help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot to add that no Riesz' lemma is allowed here (I'm taking a course in Real Analysis, though a bit tough)

Comment: Work from the definition. A finite number of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ are  uniformly bounded. Construct a function of unit norm that is more than ${1 \over 4}$ away from the finite set.

Comment: You can use the completion of $X$ whose closed unit ball is the closure of the unit ball of $X$ and hence compact (because the unit ball of $X$ is totally bounded=precompact).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the unit sphere in $(C[0,1], \| \cdot\|_1)$ compact?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679010/is-the-unit-sphere-in-c0-1-cdot-1-compact)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: In $S$ you can find $f_1, f_2, \dots $ such that $d(f_m,f_n)=2$ for $m\ne n.$ Why? Because you can find pairwise disjoint closed intervals $I_1,I_2, \dots$ of positive length contained in $[0,1].$